# Tmux: create pane if I'm not in edge

Tags: shell, vim, tmux

I want to create some same function like Nick Nisi's window management in vim (if I'm in the edge, create a new window(in vim)/pane, otherwise just move). 
I don't know how to check, if I'm in the edge..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are formats for this: pane_at_left, pane_at_right, pane_at_top, pane_at_bottom.